# How to get a excerpt content of a node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am having a node reference.How can i get its excerpt content?

For getting title or body we use:-

```
print $entry->title;
print $entry->body;
```

How i can get the excerpt of that node.(i am using excerpt module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The teaser of a node is contained in `$entry->teaser`; if the field is not initialized, then the function [`node_teaser()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_teaser/6) is the function used to build the teaser.

If the module is saving a custom value as excerpt, you should verify which is the property used from the module (I would check `$entry->excerpt`, though).
I would suggest you to install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel), which has some debug functions, including `dsm()` that allows to inspect any PHP value, and also adds a tab "Devel" for each node.

Answer (score 2):

For the stock teaser, it would be $entry->teaser but your best bet is to use

```
drupal_set_message(print_r($entry, true))
```

and look through the key=>value pairs.

For a better looking array, install the Devel module and use

```
dsm($entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you var_dump $entry? Does it have more data?